# СПП с придаточным уступки?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

*Так Феликс Боярчик нежданно-негаданно угодил в плен, хотя изо всей силы он хотел умереть.*

Расчлененная структура. Придаточное уступительное (союз ХОТЯ). Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расчлененная структура, придаточное уступительное, всё верно.